Faraday too many requests when using openai ruby gem?
When following the openai ruby gem docs:
response = client.chat(        
     parameters: {    
           model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", # Required.    
         messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Hello!"}], # Required.    
         temperature: 0.7,    
     })    
puts response.dig("choices", 0, "message", "content")    

# /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/faraday-2.9.0/lib/faraday/response/raise_error.rb:34:in `on_complete': the server responded with s  tatus 429 (Faraday::TooManyRequestsError)

but this is the very first request to the OpenAI API, so it's odd that it's 'Too many requests'.

This has nothing to do with Ruby, Rails, or even software development. You had insufficient quota on some arbitrary API to make requests, which typically does yield a 429.

@user229044 429 Too many requests is for when too many requests are made within a given time period (intended for use with rate-limiting schemes). When a user has a valid API key but insufficient credit a 403 Forbidden or 402 Payment Required accompanied by a clear error message indicating insufficient credit is more appropriate.

I had this problem and the error message seemed a bit unrelated to the underlying cause, so figured I'd share what solved (for me, anyway).
Basically I had to add credit to the OpenAI API account. See here, but basically:

Go to OpenAI API settings:
Click on 'Billing'
Click on 'Add to credit balance'
Wait a few minutes (it took about 3 minutes until it worked for me)

Now it works:
response = client.chat(
    parameters: {
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", # Required.
        messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Hello!"}], # Required.
        temperature: 0.7,
    })
puts response.dig("choices", 0, "message", "content")
Hello! How can I assist you today?
=> nil

I'm not sure why it gives a 429 error code.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers
